# Code First doing strange migration when I add an interface to my entities

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a strange problem with code first:

In project my entities looks like that and code first was doing migrations fine.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I decided to add an interface to my project like this one

```
public interface IEntity
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

My new class now looks like that:

```
public class MyEntity : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I try a migration with Code First, instead of adding a column here is what is doing code first:

- DropForeignKey
- DropIndex
- Tries to CreateTable MyEntity table and breaks telling me this table already exists

Any idea why code first tries to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using EF5 I couldn't get it to repro.  In general with migrations the order in which commands are executed is important so as the metadata is consistent between the database and models.

The correct order for these operations would be to either:

a) Run Enable-Migrations, Add-Migration  then Update-Database before populating the database (i.e. running the app) then Add-Migration and Update database after each model change before running the app

b) run the app, Enable-Migrations, change the model, Add-Migrations, Update-Database, again making sure to run update the database after each model change is made

also note I am using a very simple DbContext that looks as such:

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext  
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```